# Create a folder in C# project dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have to create a folder in `C#` project dynamically and add files to it.

Tried the below code , but it creates the folder inside the `bin` folder. I need to create in the project running path itself.

//Code:

```
// Specify a name for your top-level folder. 
string folderName = @"..\Top-Level Folder";

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: You should use the correct path. "..\" steps one directory up. Maybe use Environment for systemfolders or extract the current running path.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the main path itself"? The application will create folders relative to the current directory, which is the \bin folder, or wherever your application is running from.

Comment: the executable is in \bin\Debug folder, so it just comes out of Debug folder and creates in bin folder. Make it "string folderName = @"..\..\Top-Level Folder";" But not advisable if you are not planning to use the executable in some other folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this

```
 string projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
 string folderName = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Top-Level Folder");
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you can use the project properties to create pre/post build actions.

The reason it was created under `bin` folder is that the code is run from `bin/debug`

If you can say what you are trying to do maybe there is better solution for it